# How to kill ambient transaction?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, transactions, ssms

I have a program, which is related to database. I need to unit-test some methods from class, which represents repository. I've decided to do it without `localdb`, but using `Rollback` attribute implementation:

```
public class Rollback : Attribute, ITestAction
{
    private TransactionScope transaction;

    public void BeforeTest(ITest test)
    {
        transaction = new TransactionScope();
    }

    public void AfterTest(ITest test)
    {
        transaction.Dispose();
    }

    public ActionTargets Targets => ActionTargets.Test;
}
```

I've got that from the Internet. This attribute implicitly begins transaction before method's code, and rolls it back after. That really works nice.

But at one moment I've wanted to debug this test:

```
    [Test, Rollback]
    public async Task AddingExistingDictionaryTypeThrowsExceptionTest()
    {
        await _repository.AddDictionaryType(tempDictionaryTypeName, tempDictionaryTypeDescription);

        Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => { await _repository.AddDictionaryType(tempDictionaryTypeName, tempDictionaryTypeDescription); });
    }
```

`AddDictionaryType` - is a method from repository. It adds new entity to database after checking, if such record doesn't exist already:

```
    public async Task AddDictionaryType(string name, string description)
    {
        try
        {
            var sameNameCollection = _dbContext.DictionaryTypes.FromSqlRaw(@$"select * from dictionary_type where name = '{name}'");
            var sameDescriptionCollection = _dbContext.DictionaryTypes.FromSqlRaw(@$"select * from dictionary_type where description = '{description}'");

            if (sameNameCollection.Any() || sameDescriptionCollection.Any())
            {
                throw new AddingExistingDictionaryException();
            }

            _dbContext.Add(new DictionaryType(name, description));
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
```

Don't pay attention to two `SELECTS`, I know, that I may make one check, but that's for my needs.

So, I've set the point after first call of `AddDictionaryType` method to check new record in database, after that I've done `SELECT` in `SSMS`(I know, that was silly, too, because method worked in transaction) from same table, in which I've tried to insert record. So, I've got an error. And now I will tell you about most interesting:

After that I can't normally execute the test, I always get error: "This connection was used with the ambient transaction. The original ambient transaction needs to be completed before this connection can be used outside of it".

So I think, that there is that transaction, which hasn't been closed.

The problem is that I cannot find it and kill.

I've operated with such queries to find it:

SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses;

SELECT * from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction with(nolock);

SELECT * from sys.dm_tran_active_transactions;

EXEC SP_who2;

SELECT * FROM sys. dm_exec_sessions;

SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL);

I've seen processes, tried to kill them, didn't help.
I've reloaded server, didn't help.
There is no any information about such transaction in transaction log.

No I see, that testing like this is a big problem, because I don't even know, how that transaction could be named to rollback it by my hands.

May be it's not because of transaction? But I don't have any ideas. What about you?

Comment: if you use `using` blocks on trasnaction objects, they would be rolled back automatically. Don't roll your own exception handling. `catch {throw ex;` is just plain wrong for example.

Comment: @Charlieface, Did I understand you right? You say, that using blocks roll any database changes back? I don't think so)) May be I misunderstand...  As for throwing: I throw my own exceptions, I need them.

Comment: I *do* think so. A `using` block calls `TransactionScope.Dispose` for which [the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose?view=net-5.0#remarks) "The use of the C# using construction ensures that this method is called even if an exception occurs. Exceptions that occur after calling this method may not affect the transaction. This method also restores the ambient transaction to it original state." `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` just rethrows the original exception, but wipes the stack trace, it is not useful.

Comment: @Charlieface,  Oh, I've understood, thank you. But what what do you want me to put into using statement? Repository object? Or TransactionScope object?

Comment: The `TransactionScope` object. Anything that holds it must also be in a `using`

Comment: @Charlieface, do you mean remove Rollback attribute and use using statement with TransactionScope object? Anyway, how it will help to close ambient transaction?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't use NUnit, but guessing the `TransactionScope.Dispose` is not being called, and therefore the connection is still holding on to the transaction. Note that it's not necessarily actually started a server transaction, this is internal to the connection object (it will only `BEGIN TRAN` at the first command).

Comment: @Charlieface, I'm sure, that it's really being disposed, because before I've tried to debug the test, everything worked well, there were no added records in the database.

Comment: Also, give that you have an `await`, try `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)`

Answer (score 2):

I've refused using `Rollback` attribute, but follow
Charlieface's advice. Now I use `using` statement in each test, and everything works nice:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        using (var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            // test logic
        }
    }
```

Also, I've understodd, that there is know any stuck transaction in database.